# Transform json into table where attributes come columns and objects come rows

Tags: json, r, rstudio, jsonlite, rjson

I'm running some scripts in version 3.4.1 using Rstudio.

What I need ?
Transform json into table where attributes come columns and objects come rows

That's the script:

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

url <- 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2004/1/results.json'
res <- fromJSON(file=url)
drivers <- res$MRData$RaceTable$Races$Results[[1]]$Driver
colnames(drivers)
```

The result that I hope is something like

```
   givenName    familyName code nationality
1    Michael    Schumacher  MSC      German
2     Rubens   Barrichello  BAR   Brazilian
3   Fernando        Alonso  ALO     Spanish
4       Ralf    Schumacher  SCH      German
5       Juan Pablo Montoya  MON   Colombian
6     Jenson        Button  BUT     British
7      Jarno        Trulli  TRU     Italian
8      David     Coulthard  COU     British
9     Takuma          Sato  SAT    Japanese
10 Giancarlo    Fisichella  FIS     Italian
```

Comment: `drivers = drivers[,c(4,5,2,7)]`

Comment: but the var "drivers" return NULL ever ...

Comment: Try `res <- fromJSON(txt=url)`

Comment: 209/5000
There is no problem with "res".
The problem is when I start the "drivers".
The "drivers" variable will return "NULL"

Apparently the problem in the line

`drivers<- res$MRData$RaceTable$Races$Results[[1]]$Driver`

Comment: Worked for me. R 3.1.2

Comment: I think you may have your libraries confused: `jsonlite::fromJSON()` doesn't have a `file` argument. You may be using `library(rjson)` in stead. (Both libraries have a `fromJSON` function.)

Comment: so replace `fromJSON(file=url)` with `jsonlite::fromJSON(url)` and it will work